# How should I use my database class in other class?

Tags: php, database, oop, wrapper

I have one database wrapper class. How should I use this class object to execute query in other class?

```
$liveresellerdb=new Database('host','user','spswd','db');
$fetch = $liveresellerdb->getResult($select_resellerData);
```

How should I include the database object in my one class?

```
Class one 
{
    function a (){
       $sql="select * from table ";
       //how should i execute here my query i mean to say 
       //every time i can't create the new object 
       // i want to know the good method by which i just execute the query by
       // giving the database name    
    }
}
```

Comment: much better question then the last post !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd advise against the Singleton pattern (using static members is a variation of this pattern) and use Dependency Injection instead. This means that you pass the database object to your service (the class that uses the connection) through the constructor.

Here is an example.

```
class UserFinder
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct(Database $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function findAllActive()
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = 1';

        return $this->db->executeAndFetchAll($sql);
    }
}

$db = new Database($host, ...);
$finder = new UserFinder($db);

$users = $finder->findAllActive();
```

This ensures that you are not bound to a specific implementation of the Database class (you could make a sub-class) and will allow you to create separate `UserFinder`s with separate `Database` instances. It will also make it easier to write tests for your application because you have less dependencies, which are not hidden and also replaceable.

In short: Use dependency injection.

Comment: But i have 2 3 databases instance

Comment: Exactly, so one UserFinder instance is always tied to one database instance.

Answer (score 2):

Since global variables are dirty (you always need the `global $var;` statement), the easiest solution is to store them in a static member of a class, e.g. `Database::$db`.

Another solution (in a proper OOP environment) would be passing the database instance to the classes - in your code it would be the constructor of `one` which accepted the instance and then stored in a private member variable.

Comment: Please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324300/while-making-the-static-class-for-database-getting-this-error

Comment: I see benefit in using static class that no need to pass the database object to each class  what is the benefit in using oops conceps

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, you should think about implementing your `Database` class according to a [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

---

*Updated (according to comment below):*

Ok. I have only one suggestion here (except passing object via method's parameters and Dependency Injection, described in [igorw's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323976/how-should-i-use-my-database-class-in-other-class/5324350#5324350))...

Dependency Injection is a good way, but this case you - I suppose - have some small amount of databases, so it can be better to save them all in some static private array and get by keys.

So you will have only one public static method `getInstance($key)` and keys can be stored as some predefined constants (to avoid "spelling" errors).

This way you don't require initialization at all (`getInstance($key)` can create new Database objects with necessary parameters [passed to constructor] depending on the $key parameter). Dependency Injection looks better in general, but in some particular cases this way can be easier-to-use.

Comment: But i want multiple database instances , means i need to connect to multiple databases.

Comment: so then you create a generic database class that you can get / create new database connections.

Answer (score 1):

Could be ok to have a Db setAdapter method that store database connections in a static property by name:

```
Db::setAdapter('db1', 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . $dbname, $user, $pass);
Db::setAdapter('db2', 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . $dbname2, $user2, $pass2);
```

Then a getAdapter method that will return a database connection when needed:

```
Db::getAdapter(); // return the default one
Db::getAdapter('db2'); // return an instance by its name
```

Behind the scenes you could implement a lazy connection too.